# Type The value of attribute "source" associated with an element type "Context" must not contain the '<' character. server.xml

Tags: java, xml, apache, jersey

Does anyone know what this error mean, I looked at the xml file but I don't see the problem.
    The value of attribute "source" associated with an element type "Context" must not contain the '<' character.   server.xml  /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config line 129    XML Problem

Here is the snippet from server.xml

```
<Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
  <!--
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
  -->

  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l    %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>


  <Context docBase="MyService" path="/MyService" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyService"/></Host>
</Engine>
```